# selenium ide chrome extension -- load unpacked -- Manifest file is missing or unreadable Could not load manifest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, selenium-ide, katalon-recorder

Eventually I want to make some changes in source code of selenium IDE and deploy it as extension in chrome browser. For that I have downloaded source code of selenium ide from  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide . But when I upload code thru "load unpacked", I get error "Manifest file is missing or unreadable Could not load manifest.".

Please help.

Comment: @wOxxOm : But, I have downloaded the source code from a standard place github of the selenium ide code. Shouldn't it work out of the box?.

Comment: @wOxxOm : selenium "ide" ?. It's a recorder and playback extension from selenium for chrome and firefox.

Comment: @wOxxOm : Thanks for the pointer. Actually selenium ide comes as chrome extension. I downloaded and installed the extension. It's working. I downloaded the source code from github, but it doesn't get installed using "load packed". If not, what is the purpose of that hosted code on github. I am not able to understand what is the missing piece here?. Also, the source code does have manifest.json but it is somewhere deep inside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218156/discussion-between-meen639-and-woxxom).

Comment: Ah, I guess you need to build it to load as an extension.

Comment: it is written in javascript. so I guess we shouldnt need to build it, as it is interpreted. There is similar recorder and playback extension katalon recorder. I was able to install its source code as chrome extension by uploading code thru "load unpacked". Katalon recorder is compatible with selenium ide.. not sure whats wrong with selenium ide..

Comment: Extension need to have manifest.json so you need to do something to make it appear, whatever the process is called.